# Landscape and Portrait Orientations for iPad Apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, orientation, landscape

I know this question has been asked for many times. I've searched but didn't get the proper answer which one will be able to implement nicely.

Question : How can I handle the Landscape and Portrait Orientations for iPad Apps ?

Note : In interface builder's Size Inspector -> Autosizing we can set the orientations for Images but when we have a complex view how can I change the orientation from Portrait to Landscape nicely ? If we need to call different .xib , how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `UIViewController` reference document

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

These contain methods like `didRotate`, `willRotate` etc and u can override them according to your needs. When the rotation of the view occurs u can adjust the view's size through the auto-sizing options. You can know more about auto-resizing options in `UIView` reference document

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Pls go through the UIViewAutoresizing part.